# Able to display one row but not loop it through

Tags: php, for-loop

I'm working on displaying data on a table. It works to display one row of data but I can't seem to loop it. It keeps saying "*Undefined offset: 0*", "* *", "*Undefined offset: 2 *" and keeps looping the error to the number of my results.

Here is my code: (this does not work)

```
 <?php
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($Results); $i++) {
            echo "
             <tr>
            <td>{$Results[$i]['Namn']}</td>  
            <td>{$Results[$i]['Efternamn']}</td
            <td></td>

             </td>
       </tr>
    ";
        }
        ?>
```

This works when I'm displaying one row only.

```
 <?php

            echo "
             <tr>
            <td>{$Results['Namn']}</td>
            <td>{$Results['Efternamn']}</td>
            <td></td>

             </td>
       </tr>
    ";

        ?>
```

**Edit**:
How I get $Results:

This is from my controller layer (MVC)

```
$displayResults = new Sok($name, $aftername);

    $Results = $displayResults->getSearchResult();

    include "../view/test.php";
```

Comment: use a foreach rather for loop

Comment: can you show how you get $results?

Comment: also can you post output of $results also print_r($Results);

Comment: Yes. it work but it only prints out one row..

Comment: so you have only one row in results

Comment: Yes. I realized I wrote `mysql_fetch_assoc`instead of `mysql_fetch_array`..

Comment: @RakeshSharma Thank you very much. You made me realize the problem.

Comment: /!\ `mysql_*` commands are deprecated. Use PDO or MySQLi instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if your loop contain name [0] , name [1] then write $Results['Namn'][$i]
```

and if it not show error at $Results['Namn'] it means $Results['Namn'] is not an array further (no 0 , 1 , .... position of $Results['Namn'])

Comment: you welcome and mark ans as correct if your problem is solve @David j

Answer (score 0):

Just try to implement it such a way :

```
<?php
        foreach ($Results as $result) {
            echo "
             <tr>
            <td>{$result['Namn']}</td>  
            <td>{$result['Efternamn']}</td
            <td></td>
             </td>
       </tr>";
        }
 ?>
```

Hope it helps....